# Java, convert object to softreference

Tags: java, memory-management, soft-references, weakhashmap

I need to put a data object into my weakhashmap containing softreferences. How do I convert my "Drawable" object into a softreference?

```
WeakHashMap <String, SoftReference<Drawable>> tempPulled = new WeakHashMap<String,     SoftReference<Drawable>>();
Drawable pulled = BitmapDrawable.createFromResourceStream(null, null, conn.getInputStream(), "galleryImage", options);
SoftReference<Drawable> sPulled;            
tempPulled.put(id, pulled);
```

tempPulled should be putting "sPulled" , the softreference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
SoftReference<Drawable> sPulled = new SoftReference<Drawable>(pulled);
```

But you probably want to add a queue to remove the SoftRefence from the map should the referenced object be removed (or your cache will grow with keys and empty softrefences.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Guava's MapMaker](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) class, which allows you to specify soft values.  Way easier than reimplementing it yourself.

Comment: I am using built-in classes. Not reinventing anything